# How show few turtles at a time?

Tags: simulation, agent, netlogo

I have this basic code for setup and moving turtle.
By this time I want only few turtles to appear during setup and then when they move. Other turtles will show or will become visible.

```
to setup
crt 100
setxy random 19 random 80
end

to go
fd 1
end
```

---

I tried this. But I got error

```
to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles random 10
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  fd 1
  if count turtles < 100 [
    create-turtles min list (random 10) (100 - count turtles)
  ]
  tick
end
```

Comment: Can you be more clear and specific about what you want to happen? I don't understand your description.

Comment: Like when I start to setup I don't want all 100 turtle to appear. Like first 5 turtles will appear then when it start to go another 5 will appear, next 7 or 8 or 2 and so on until 100 will come out.

Comment: You might look at the Ant Lines model in the Biology section of Sample Models, which has ants that gradually emerge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not that clear, if you want to be able to set visibility of turtles you should use hidden? Primitive to set visibility of turtles, 
Following example shows how turtles appear when their who id is smaller than ticks, in tick 101 all turtles will be visible.

```
to setup
  clear-all
  reset-ticks
  crt 100 [
    set hidden? true
    setxy random 19 random 80
  ]


end

to go
  ask turtles
  [
    if who < ticks
    [
      set hidden? false
      fd 1
    ]
    ]

  ask patch 0 0 [set plabel ticks] ; just for your info
  ask patch 1 1 [set plabel "Ticks"] ; just for your info
  tick
end
```

After 1 tick only one turtle is visible:

[image]

And now 40 turtles are visible :

[image]

**Update:**

In this example, you can have a list of numbers that you want to ask turtles to set their visibility to true:

```
globals [ number-to-set-visible]
to setup
  clear-all
  reset-ticks
  set number-to-set-visible [ 5 5 7 8 2  ]
  crt 100 [
    set hidden? true
    setxy random 19 random 80
  ]


end

to go
  if visibility-condition and length number-to-set-visible > 0 

    [
      ask n-of item 0 number-to-set-visible turtles [

        set hidden? false
        ]

      set number-to-set-visible remove-item 0 number-to-set-visible
      ] 

     ask turtles with [not hidden? ]
     [
      fd 1

     ]


  tick
end

to-report visibility-condition
 report ticks mod 100 = 0 and ticks > 0
end
```

Comment: How about random number of turtles not by ones. like first 4 then 9 then 5 and so on.

Comment: I have added a list such as [5 5 7 8 2 ... ] and then you can have a condition which if its true you can ask n-of items in the list turtles to set their visibility.

Comment: In visibility-condition just put any condition which you need to make turtles appear, for example if pcolor of a patch is a specific color or ticks is greater than X or anything else

Answer (score 1):

Marzy's answer covers how to create invisible turtles during `setup`, then gradually make them visible during `go`.

It's not clear to me if you actually need this visible/invisible distinction. Do you actually need all the turtles to exist from the beginning? Might it be OK to just create a few more turtles each tick? If so, try code like this:

```
to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles random 10
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  if count turtles < 100 [
    create-turtles min list (random 10) (100 - count turtles)
  ]
  tick
end
```

Comment: What if I want to add fd 1.

Comment: Add `ask turtles [ fd 1 ]`.